# MS Visual Studio - How do I use a button to Sort my combobox variables?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I searched and only found how to sort combobox variables through the Properties sidebar. This will not work for what I'm trying to do.

I have a textbox where the user will type in a name. They click the Add button, and the name is added to the combobox options. Let's say I add "Bob" then "Andy" then "Carl". In the combobox it would list them in that order.

I need to use a button that will sort these names alphabetically. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the "Sorted" in properties to true, I set it so that when you click the button, it would do this. So the "Sort" button code would look like this:

ComboBox1.Sorted = True

Answer (score 0):

Put them in an array and use Array.Sort then back into the combobox

Comment: I'm kind of new to VS so I've never used an array. What would the code look like? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: i believe you can use ComboBox.Items.CopyTo(arry, 0) but i dont have VS on this PC to check

Comment: Ok, for my "SortButton_Click" I did "ComboBox1.Items.CopyTo(Array, 0)". It gives an error and says " 'Array' is a type and cannont be used as an expression."